# Laravel redirect back and refresh.

Tags: laravel

I have following task. I need to upload image on ftp server via post form. Next I need to refrash page and i would like to see the new photo. Please, look on my code and you understand my task better.

First, I sending photo on /shops/update/{id} url. This is part of my form.

[image]

Next, I have following route:
[image]

And, of course, I have method updateShop in the controller

[image]

The method will make url for image, send image on hosting and return redirect to shop info page (the page, where shop's form is situated).
All this things work very nice, but after uploading a photo, I need to press ctrl + f5, and after this action new picture will on tha page. 
I know that in old laravel version there was refrash() method. But now redirect()->back()->refrash() does not work. Maybe this happaning becouse of view's cache. I have tried somethink like this Artisan::call('view:clear'); But this code does not work too.

Comment: You can just add a timestamp at the end of the file name to get around caching. Example: `<img src="image.jpg?version=time()"`